# Compile OpenGL in emscripten

Tags: c++, linker, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to compile an OpenGL game for Webassembly using emscripten.
However, when linking the code, I receive the following undefined symbols messages:

```
wasm-ld: error:  undefined symbol: glGetTexImage
wasm-ld: error:  undefined symbol: gluErrorString
```

I have already checked that I'm linking with "glut", "GLU" and "GL".